# Text inside the div need to be splitted and ... show be show if the text is long

Tags: html, css

I have one requirement in which i need to show the text inside the div. There are few condition like, if the text length is too long i need to split the text and show it to the second line

```
e.g: 
Input:
Hello Every Body this is long text

Output:
Hello Every Body
This is...
```

i have tried to implement the solution by us the below css,

```
 .div{
     overflow: hidden;
     text-overflow: ellipsis;
     -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
     display: -webkit-box;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
     line-height: 10px;
     height: 20px;
     font-size:13px;
     text-align: left;
     }
```

But the problem is if the first text itself is too long like:

> Helooooooooooooooooooo this is text

The result is not comming correct

Answer (score 2):

Try `word-break` property,

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Comment: i tried its working Hellooiiiiiiiiooooooob ssss the text  this is long but its possible to show the first character in the same line e.g:                              Heloooiiiiiooobbbb                                                                                             sss..

Comment: What do you mean? Please update question with new screenshot.

Comment: Please see edited question **"Expected Output little modification" **

Comment: is not comming in mozilla beacuse -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
     display: -webkit-box;
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical; are not working there. What can be used in mozilla instead of these.

Answer (score 0):

**Using** **ellipsis**

```css
.overflow {
  width: 120px;
  height:30px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  /**
   * Required properties to achieve text-overflow
   */
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow ellipsis">This is an example text showing nothing interesting but the truncated content via text-overflow shorthand property.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3w4of87/)

HTML

```
<div class="div">
Helooooooooooooooooooo this is text
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div{
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 line-height: 10px;
 height: 20px;
 font-size:13px;
 text-align: left;
 word-break: break-all;
 width:50px;
 background:#ccc;
 }
```